# query custom fields joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla

I have added a custom fields on the user management, which works greats, the custom fields are save  on  **fields** **fields_values** tables, I don't find a way to join the info from user table **users** table and the fields tables in one query results.

I need something like: `SELECT id,NAME,username,customfield FROM users WHERE Id=2`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: It's 'achieve'. Try JOIN.

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry for the spelling correction,  you said to  join, but I don't see what table to join with in order to get the result I want, don't you?

Comment: Which value should be extracted from `fields_values`? This question is a little too incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.*, field_id as fid, value as fvalue FROM `#__users` as u  LEFT JOIN `#__fields_values` AS f ON u.id = f.item_id WHERE u.id=2

// u as user table
// f as fileds table
// u.id as userid (user table user id)
// f.item_id as userid (fields table user id)
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to future researchers if you provide your answer using the Joomla query methods.

Comment: Do you know how to do this? (I don't mean to be condescending)

Comment: am a  Joomla Developer for last 5yrs

Comment: Great.  Well, since the `#_` needs Joomla to fill in the prefix and because this is tagged with Joomla, you might be so kind to post how to construct this query using Joomla query building methods.

Comment: I have build my project multi tables joining  and  learning query language, but this query lack in performance. so i need to improve

Answer (score 0):

I found this link: https://ubiq.co/database-blog/transpose-rows-columns-dynamically-mysql/
which helped me to create a pure MySQL solution:

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        'max(case when `f`.`name` = ''',
        `f`.`name`,
        ''' then `fv`.`value` end) `',
        `f`.`name`,
        '`'
    ) INTO @sql
FROM `#__fields` `f` 
JOIN `#__fields_groups` `fg` ON `f`.`group_id`=`fg`.`id`
WHERE `f`.`context`='com_users.user' ORDER BY `fg`.`ordering`,`f`.`ordering`;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `u`.*, ', @sql, ' 
FROM `#__users` `u`
JOIN `#__fields_values` `fv` ON `u`.`id`=`fv`.`item_id`
JOIN `#__fields` `f` ON `fv`.`field_id`=`f`.`id`
GROUP BY `u`.`id` ORDER BY `u`.`name`');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Also answered here: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/31797/how-to-join-custom-fields-data-to-users-table-without-extra-rows-in-result-set/